# What advantages are there on using GWT over a php framework such as Yii

Tags: java, php, gwt, yii

I am about to start developing a private TODO website (that later will be extended to Web applications). I am unsure what framework to use. I have read about GWT and PHP frameworks such as Yii. What advantages do each one have over another.

Background
 - experience in Java 
 - got an apache web host that supports php

Doubts:

- Would developing in GWT mean that refactoring would be easier than developing in PHP (especially since you can use Eclipse)
- seems like PHP frameworks such as Yii design objects for you once you create database layout ... can this be done with GWT?

Thanks!

Comment: PHP is much more flexible than Java, but at the cost of code ambiguity.

Comment: advantage - no need to use/learn PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One big difference I haven't seen mentioned in the question or answers/comments is that Yii is a server-side framework, which runs entirely on your own/hosted server, whereas GWT compiles to JavaScript, and is therefore runs in the client's browser only. These two offerings (and ideas) serve very different purposes, and can be used together.

When using GWT to build the client, the server can be built using any tool desired, so long as it exposes data to the JS-based client. That can be in the form of JSON or XML, or some other data encoding (GWT's built in RPC, for example, can pass complex object graphs to and from a Java servlet container).

If you were to use them together, Yii could be used to create PHP objects from the database schema/layout, and to build the various rules for authentication/authorization so the client can read and write data. GWT could then be used to build a client which reads and updates that data, making calls to services exposed by Yii/PHP code.

Comment: +1 for the distinction between client-side GWT and server-side PHP.

Comment: aha! that is interesting! its good to distinguish the server side and client side. Question: java servlets run on the backened correct? does GWT produce java servlets? and if it does, GWT can produce code for both front end and back end?

Comment: GWT can work with Java servlets, and ships with some servlets, but only generates code for the client. Since most GWT code is in Java, some code can be shared with the server, but not all - the main candidates to share are model objects and some validation kinds of things, but things like services and DB calls are best for the server, whereas widgets and data binding are best for the client. There are Java libs that cover the work of turning objects into DB calls, but GWT isn't one of them - it serves a different purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If you like Eclipse you can certainly stay with Eclipse and still develop in PHP. The PHP tools from eclipse.org are very good and the IDE plugin from Aptana is even better.

Regarding Yii vs GWT, it really depends on your language of choice. If you are highly proficient in Java and really like the strong typing of the Java language then GWT is a good choice (although there are certainly other choices that keep you in the Java world such as Tapestry). PHP frameworks vary quite widely in how much they embrace OOP and concepts such as creating your business objects based on your database. Yii definitely stands out as a framework due to the code generation capabilities built in. That will definitely help you if you're getting started with PHP.